# Is there a library that can take an image and do processing to determine things about it?

Tags: image-recognition

Is there a library that can take an image and do processing to determine things about it (such as: is the image a person of female or male)?

Is there such a free tool out there?

Comment: You need to give more information. What language? Apply some more relevant tags to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some. But most of them are extremely expensive (several 100k € - don't know if that is acceptable for you).
One open source is [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), but you can be happy if it can actually detect a face. It won't detect the sex of a person on the picture.